# PyInstaller: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user123\\AppData\\Roaming\\pyinstaller\\bincache00_py37_32bit

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I try to use PyInstaller on my windows machine I get the following error message:

"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\user123\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py37_32bit"

What I found out: PyInstaller is searching a lot of files in the directory "AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py37_32bit". All the files are located in my machine in the directory "C:\Python\Python37-32\DLLs".

Is there a setting or something to tell the PyInstaller the correct folder?

Error message when I try to run pyinstaller:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\user123\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache00_py37_32bit\python37.dll'